# Reactive Approach To Using Temp Lookup Map

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor

I have existing code I'd like to make more reactive, using RxJava or Proj. Reactor.  I'm struggling with it a bit.

Given a list of CatalogRequests, some of which may be for the same CatalogItem but with a different condition (NEW vs. varying levels of USED), I want to:

1. Fetch distinct CatalogItems by their itemId.  Data for all conditions is stored in the same row, so I only need to make a request for the same item once.
2. Once I have distinct items, go through my list of requests and perform some logic that transforms those requests with the distinct CatalogItem I have just looked up.

   ```
   class CatalogRequest {
       String itemId;
       Integer condition;
   }

   //class does not look like this, simplified for the question
   class CatalogItem {
        Map<Condition, Money> usedPrices;
        Map<Condition, DateTime> availableDate;
   }

   //non reactive code
   public List<CatalogResponse> fetchResponses(List<CatalogRequest> requests) {
   List<CatalogItem> items = requests.stream().map(CatalogRequest::getItemId)
       .distinct()
       .collect(toList());

   List<Optional<CatalogItem>> cachedResults = items.stream()
       .map (this::fetchItem)
       .map (CompletableFuture::join)
       .filter(Optional::isPresent)
       .collect(toList());

   List<CatalogResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
   requests.forEach( request -> 
       {
            CatalogResponse response = transformResponse(request, cachedResults.get(request.getItemId());
            responses.add(response);
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: well, it's seems very easily convertible to Observable instead of streams ,most of the operators are the same (map, distinct, filter), but the question is why are you trying to make it more 'reactive', where is your async code here? it's seems all like in memory collections, so what's wrong with streams?

Comment: Please don't pollute StackOverflow with "why would you do that" answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your algorithm and use case isn't IMHO well adapted to a reactive programming pattern**. That is because it "joins" information from 2 collections (the requests and the cached responses) and can only do that after all the data has been processed, as opposed to processing that can be done progressively, item by item.

It is not even easily solved by combining operators like `zip` because data is filtered and not guaranteed to come in same order or cardinality.

(btw. there is an **issue** with `cachedResults.get(request.getItemId())` I think, since this is a list and not a map there's no guarantee that request item id correctly maps to the list's index).

So converting the first steps of `fetchResponses` is easy enough, but not the last step.

**For reference, here is how I would go about migrating some of that code:**

You could maybe change `fetchItem()` to return a `Mono` (eg. using `Mono.fromCallable()`, depending on what fetch actually does). Note that if fetch uses an `ExecutorService` internally, then you'll need to ensure your Mono is also similarly executed in another threading context, using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` for example...

Then you can start migrating the code in `fetchResponses`. I don't think starting with a collection of `CatalogRequests` is a problem if you have collected those in memory without any particular latency. If not, you can always migrate the parent code too to call the method with a `Flux<CatalogRequest>` instead and asynchronously react to each request.

The list can be converted to a `Flux` using `Flux.fromIterable(requests)`, then filtered for duplicates using `.distinct()`.

Here is a change: don't collect yet but continue building up your async sequence.

Do a `.flatMap(this::fetchItem)` to asynchronously retrieve the rows. You might not even need this method to return an `Optional`, since an empty flux/mono would be equivalent, and ignored by `flatMap`.

But at this point, you're kind of stuck with reverting back to `.collectList().block()` and reuse the imperative code.

If you could find a declarative way of performing the same task (think using a single `Stream`), things would be much more adaptable to reactive programming.